# navigation to example in topic outline of documentation

Tags: feature-request, documentation, documentation-topics

The topic outline of a tag in documentation is a great way to navigate in big topics like [HTML - input control elements](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/html/277/input-control-elements#t=201702142039443778928).

[image]

But I miss the navigation to that example. When I click on a title in the outline, I'll scroll direct to that example.

Also a button *"back to top"* I miss on the topic page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partly [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

This feature is added in an update of the documentation, but the *"back to top"* button is stil missing.